# ASP.NET 2 DataValuefield within DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am having a problem in ASP.NET. I have a table names Articles with these columns in Database:

Column 1:
[image]

Column 2:
[image]

Column 3:
[image]

I have a dropdownlist like this DropDownList1.DataTextField = "PERSHKRIM";

What I want to do is when I choose a product from DropDownList for example if I choose `dropuct aa` in a Label it will show `PROD1` from Column 2 and in a second label it will show `111` from Column 3.

My code is this:

```
DataTable listaArtikujt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection lidhje = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEN1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Articles]", lidhje);
        adapter.Fill(listaArtikujt);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = listaArtikujt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "PERSHKRIM";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "KOD";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

NOTE again: These columns are in one table names `Articles`.

Comment: So, what is your question? Do you get any error or exception message? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Soner Gönül There will be 2 Labels. One for column 2 and one for Column 3. Column 1 is attached with dropdownlist. If I chose something from dropdownlist (for example Product 2 which is in Column 1) in Label1.Text will output "PROD 2" which is on column 2 and in Label2.Text will output "100" which is from Column 3.
I hope you understood me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this is what you are looking for:

```
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PERSHKRIM, KOD + '~' + CMSH AS KC FROM [Articles]", lidhje);
        adapter.Fill(listaArtikujt);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = listaArtikujt;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "PERSHKRIM";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "KC";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Split('~')[0].ToString();
        Label2.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Split('~')[1].ToString();
```

Note: if there will be '~' char in your records, it will cause problems. Choose most appropriate char according to your records.

Comment: It give me an error 'Error converting data type varchar to float.' There is no '~' in my records.

Comment: It's ok. I did it. I just modified the SQL code like this `SELECT PERSHKRIM, KOD + '~' + CAST(CMSH1 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS KC FROM [ARTIKUJ]` because CMSH1 dat type is float.
Thank You.